# CSS and JS Failed to load with esapi security filter while refresh

Tags: java, servlets, filter, esapi

In my project we are using esapi security filter.The problem is when we refeshing the
browser we are getting the below error in firefox.If we refresh again page is loading correctly.But alternate time its not working.

The resource from “http://localhost:8080/selva/css/bootstrap.css” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

In chrome we are getting below error but its coming randomly for every 20 requests.But refreshing no issue came.

Resource Interpreted MIMEType('')  failed

When I comment the esapi security filter the above issues not coming.
below is my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>selva_security</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
            com.selva.security.core.SelvaSecurityFilter
        </filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>isContentSetRequired</param-name>
      <param-value>No</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>selva_security</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

If i comment the filter.Everything working fine.

Below is my filter class

```
 public class SelvaSecurityFilter implements Filter {
    private String allowableResourcesRoot = "WEB-INF";
    public void destroy() {
    }
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
                HttpServletRequest hrequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
                HttpServletResponse hresponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                SecurityWrapperRequest secureRequest = new SecurityWrapperRequest(hrequest);
                SecurityWrapperResponse secureResponse = new SecurityWrapperResponse(hresponse);
                secureRequest.setAllowableContentRoot(allowableResourcesRoot);
                ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(secureRequest, secureResponse);        
                hresponse.addHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
                hresponse.setHeader("X-Powered-By", "");            
                hresponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1
                hresponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
                hresponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.          
        }   catch (Exception e) {

        }
        finally {

        }
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        this.allowableResourcesRoot = StringUtilities.replaceNull(filterConfig.getInitParameter("allowableResourcesRoot"),
                allowableResourcesRoot);

    }
}
```

Please find the jsp page and directory structure

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/selva/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    Directory :



Src
        Webcontent
        css
            bootstrap.css
        js
            bootstrap.js
        WEB-INF
            view
                index.jsp
            web.xml
```

How to fix this issue any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: show your jsp/html file where your css is being loaded from

Comment: thanks @Jonathan, I updated the jsp and directory structure in question

Comment: private String allowableResourcesRoot = "WEB-INF"; is your only allowable resource....

Comment: try adding: private String allowableResourcesRoot = "Webcontent";

Comment: or  private String allowableResourcesRoot = "css";

Comment: but i can able to access the image files that present in outside of WEB-INF.only doing refresh issue is came

Comment: ok @JonathanLaliberte i will change to webcontent and test

Comment: after changing to web content also issue exists